# exam2nops not processing latex commands

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-exams

I am endeavouring to create a statistics class exam with the R/exams package.  So I am creating a series of Rmd files to create the questions as per the requirements of the package.  My issue is with creating tables that appear nicely in PDF format once using the exam2nops format.

I have a small dataframe in R called Freqtable1

```
> Freqtable1
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  `Political Parties (x)` `Absolute Frequency (f)` Relative freque…¹ Perce…² Cumul…³
  <chr>                   <lgl>                    <lgl>             <lgl>   <lgl>  
1 Green Party             NA                       NA                NA      NA     
2 Bloc Québécois          NA                       NA                NA      NA     
3 Conservative Party      NA                       NA                NA      NA     
4 Liberal Party           NA                       NA                NA      NA     
5 NDP                     NA                       NA                NA      NA     
6 Total                   NA                       NA                NA      NA     
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​`Relative frequency          (2 decimals)`,
#   ²​`Percent (%) (2 decimals)`, ³​`Cumulative Frequency (2 decimals)`
```

I then convert this into a kable called FT1 with the following command:

```
FT1 <-
  kable(Freqtable1, format = "latex", align = "c", caption = "Frequency table") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position"),font_size = 16) %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, width="4.0cm",border_left = TRUE) %>%
                      column_spec(2:4, width="1.8cm") %>%
                      column_spec(5,width="1.8cm",border_right = TRUE)%>%
                      kable_styling("bordered", font_size = 11)
```

This produces the following latex code

```
\begin{table}[!h]

\caption{\label{tab:Freqtable Qs2}Frequency table}
\centering
\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont
\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}[t]{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.0cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.8cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.8cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.8cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.8cm}|}
\hline
Political Parties (x) & Absolute Frequency (f) & Relative frequency          (2 decimals) & Percent (\%) (2 decimals) & Cumulative Frequency (2 decimals)\\
\hline
Green Party &  &  &  & \\
\hline
Bloc Québécois &  &  &  & \\
\hline
Conservative Party &  &  &  & \\
\hline
Liberal Party &  &  &  & \\
\hline
NDP &  &  &  & \\
\hline
Total &  &  &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

When I run this code through exams2nops using the following code:

```
exams::exams2nops(QMT1, n=1, dir = "output", edir = "exercises",date="2023-02-19", reglength = 7, 
           blank = 1,
           duplex = F,
           envir=.GlobalEnv,
           texengine = "pdflatex",
           title = "QM First Test",
           samepage = TRUE,
           header = list(
             Date = "2023-02-19",
             #    Name = function(i) formatC(Students$Name[i])
             ID = function(i) formatC(i, width = 11, flag = "0")),
           institution = "MySchol",logo ="my.png")
```

it produces the following error.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> |>{\centering \arraybackslash 
                                         }p{4.0cm}|>{\centering \arraybacksl...
l.13 ...cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.8cm}|}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile QA-First-Test solution1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See QA-First-Test solution1.log for more info.
```

I have manually removed the `\centering\arraybackslash` and pasted the code into the Rmd file to create the pdf which works, but this completely fails to meet the standard of automating the questions.

I am running the latest version of R-studio and R as well as all the packages, as of 27-02-2023.

I am using the following packages including R/Exams
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

I would infinitely prefer using flextable package instead of knitr but the conversion to pdf seems to totally fail!

here is the contents of the .Rmd

````html
---
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  pdf_document:
    fig_width: 4
    latex_engine: pdflatex
---

Question
========
```{r Freqtable Qs, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(flextable)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(htmltools)

# knitr::opts_chunk$set(ft.tabcolsep=0, ft.latex.float = "none")
# flextable::set_flextable_defaults(fonts_ignore=TRUE)
cp <- sample(1:99,1)
ndp<- sample(1:99,1)
bq<- sample(1:99,1)
lpc<- sample(1:99,1)
gp<- sample(1:99,1)
tp <- cp+ndp+bq+lpc+gp
Freqtable1 <- readxl::read_excel("~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Aaron/Champlain/Resources/R Homework/QM Test 1/exercises/Freqtable1.xlsx")
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')

# FT1 <-
# flextable::flextable(Freqtable1) %>%
# flextable::theme_box() %>% 
#   save_as_image(path="~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Aaron/Champlain/Resources/R Homework/QM Test 1/exercises/bob.png")

# save the flextable as an HTML file


# include the HTML file in the PDF
# includeHTML(ft1_html)

#ft_image <- knitr::include_graphics(flextable::as_raster(FT1))


# FT1AP <- flextable::flextable(FT1A) %>%   flextable::theme_box() %>% save_as_image(path="~/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Aaron/Champlain/Resources/R Homework/QM Test 1/exercises/bobAnswer.png")
```
On the first day of class, a statistics professor asked all `r tp` students to report their favourite Canadian political party from a list. The data is distributed as follows: Conservative Party = `r cp` students, New Democratic Party (NDP) = `r ndp` students, Liberal Party = `r lpc` students, Green Party = `r gp` students, and Bloc Québécois = `r bq` students. (8pts total).  

Fill in the frequency table for these data. (4pts) 
```{r Freqtable Qs2, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
FT1 <-
  kable(Freqtable1, format = "latex", align = "c", caption = "Frequency table") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position"),font_size = 16) %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, width="4.0cm",border_left = TRUE) %>%
                      column_spec(2:4, width="1.8cm") %>%
                      column_spec(5,width="1.8cm",border_right = TRUE)%>%
                      kable_styling("bordered", font_size = 11)
```
`r FT1`
What is the third favourite political party among these students?

Answerlist
----------
```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}

FT1A <- Freqtable1

FT1A[,2] <- c(gp,bq,cp,lpc,ndp,tp)
FT1A[,3] <- c(round(gp/tp,2),round(bq/tp,2),round(cp/tp,2),round(lpc/tp,2),round(ndp/tp,2),tp/tp)
FT1A[,4] <- c(round(gp/tp*100,2),round(bq/tp*100,2),round(cp/tp*100,2),round(lpc/tp*100,2),round(ndp/tp*100,2),tp/tp*100)
FT1A[,5] <- c(round(gp/tp*100,2),round((gp+bq)/tp*100,2),round((gp+bq+cp)/tp*100,2),round((gp+bq+cp+lpc)/tp*100,2),round((gp+bq+cp+lpc+ndp)/tp*100,2),tp/tp*100)
FT1AP <-
  kable(FT1A, format = "latex", booktabs = FALSE,align = "c", caption = "Frequency table: Solutions") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("scale_down","hold_position")) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
 # column_spec(1, width="4.0cm",border_left = TRUE) %>%
                      column_spec(2:4, width="1.8cm") %>%
                      column_spec(5,width="1.8cm",border_right = TRUE)%>%
                      kable_styling("bordered", font_size = 11)

popp <- dplyr::arrange(FT1A,desc(FT1A[,2]))
pop1 <- popp[2,1]
pop2<- popp[3,1]
pop3<- popp[4,1]
pop4<- popp[5,1]
pop5<- popp[6,1]
```
* `r pop1`
* `r pop2`
* `r pop3`
* `r pop4`
* `r pop5`

Solution
========
```{r }

```

`r FT1AP`

Answerlist
----------
* False. `r pop1`
* False. `r pop2`
* True. `r pop3`
* False. `r pop4`
* False. `r pop5`

Meta-information
================
exname: PopularParties
extype: mchoice
exsolution: 00100
exshuffle: 4
expoints: 2
````

Comment: Could you please share a minimal reproducible example. Currently, your example is not reproducible because you do not share the actual Rmd exercise and it is not minimal because you use a lot of options that are clearly not relevant. Could you please boil this down by omitting everything that is not necessary and make the example self-contained? Then I will have a closer look.

Comment: The error message sounds as if `\usepackage{array}` is missing in your latex preamble.

Comment: Thanks! If that is the only problem, then `exams2nops(..., usepackage = "array")` should fix the problem. My suspicion is, though, that more LaTeX packages need to be included. That's why I wanted to test the solution and asked for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Patella I can't compile your code, because it uses all these locals files, but try to add `\usepackage{array}` to your header-includes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks so much!  The `exams2nops(..., usepackage = "array")` was the solution

Comment: Great. Please accept your own answer by clicking the check mark on the left of it. Then it will be flagged as solved here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks!  New here, eager to learn!  Really enjoying your package and getting it to work is quite a learning curve.  But, so far very worth it.